# .BAT equivalent for MAC

Tags: macos, batch-file, hosts

I have create a .bat file which I then converted to .exe to edit the hosts file on Windows systems. I was to conver to a shell script.

My .bat script is

```
@ECHO off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Create your list of host domains
set LIST=(www.google.com)
::Set the ip of the domains you set in the list above
set www.google.com=192.168.1.1
:: deletes the parentheses from LIST
set _list=%LIST:~1,-1%
::ECHO %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts > tmp.txt
for  %%G in (%_list%) do (
    set  _name=%%G
    set  _value=!%%G!
    SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
    ECHO Carrying out requested modifications to your HOSTS file
    ::strip out this specific line and store in tmp file
    type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v !_name! > tmp.txt
    ::re-add the line to it
    ECHO %NEWLINE%^!_value! !_name!>>tmp.txt
    ::overwrite host file
    copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
    del tmp.txt
)
ipconfig /flushdns
ECHO.
EXIT
```

I have tried following http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html but with no success.

Comment: Although you're alluding to script files, this is more of a shell/OS question and belongs at [su]. This site would be appropriate if you were having some issue actually writing a script.

Comment: I am having problems writing the script, I don't know how to or what scripting language to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Well MacOS is a Unix based System, so you can use any shell command. look for "How to Bash script"on the internet or "Sh Script"

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the host file can be done using a shell script on Mac OS X. If you want users to be able to execute the shell script as easy as possible (i.e. by double-clicking an icon), you might want to look into executing the shell script using AppleScript. The AppleScript can be stored as an executable for easily passing it around.